# getting undefined method bson_type when doing $in in mongo ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am using the latest version of the mongo driver and I am trying to do an in query.

This used to work but for some reason now doesn't and I've looked for examples of an $in in the driver but can't find anything.

```
Mongo::Logger.logger.level = ::Logger::FATAL
client = Mongo::Client.new([configatron.dbserver],
                           :database => configatron.dbname
                          )
@collection = client[collection_name]

@collection.find(
  :$and => [
    {:ShareIndex => {:$in => share_indexes}},
    {:Latest => true}]
  )
```

The exact error I am getting:

```
undefined method `bson_type' for #<Mongo::Collection::View:0x007ff9b2827130>
```

Comment: so sorry, I have will correct now, it should have read $in so share_indexes is an array like share_indexes = ['one','two']

Comment: @muistooshort your question lead me in the right direction, thanks. I forgot that I need to cast to array from MongoCollection

Comment: That's what I thought, no worries. And you don't need an `$and` operator here, just `find(:ShareIndex => { :$in => share_indexes }, :Latest => true)` should have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is not `$a` operator in mongodb

```
@collection.find({ :ShareIndex => { :$in => share_indexes }, :Latest => true })
```

Comment: yes, thank you; I changed it to an $a to test and forgot when I copied the code here. The reason why it wasn't working however was because share_indexes was a MongoCollection from a previous query and I haven't cast it to an array yet. Should not code that early in the morning :-)